# How do I do guild management?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I've created a WoW guild last night, and I'm using all avail. guild ranks.

Guild leader
XO
"real friends"
guild member rank 2
guild member rank 3
guild member rank 4
guild member rank 5
trail

Now, where do I set up user rights? I want my XO and "real friends" to be able to invite others and talk in /officer. And where do i set up guild bank settings? for now i just want it to be so that only one tab is withdrawable and the others are strictly under my control (for now). no money withdrawal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting up user ranks can be done by clicking the Guild Control button on the Info tab. There's a drop-down up the top:

- **Guild Permissions** lets you set what ranks can invite, talk in /guild and /officer, and withdraw money from the guild bank for repairs and personal use.
- **Bank Tab Permissions** lets you configure what ranks have access to what tabs.

Comment: I must be blind, did not see that. Thank you!